# Basic Questions about Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

This is not a homework. I am trying to do exercises from a textbook to understand `MST (minimum spanning tree)`.

Suppose I have a cycle `C` in a weighted undirected graph `G`. As I understand, the following is correct:

- The *heaviest* edge in `C` belongs to *no* MST of `G`. That is, there is *no* MST of `G`, which contains that edge.
- The *lightest* edge in `C` belongs to *some* MST of `G`. That is, there is an MST of `G`, which contains that edge.

Now I wonder if the followings claims are correct too.

- The *lightest* edge in `C` belongs to *all* MST of `G`. That is, there is *no* MST of `G`, which does not contain that edge.
- Any edge in `C` except the *heaviest* one belongs to *some* MST. That is, for each edge in `C` except the *heaviest* one there is an MST, which contains that edge.

Could you prove the last claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for the first claim if there are multiple edges which are lightest, all need not be included in the MST.

Answer (score 1):

The first one of your claims is always true. The lightest edge is on the MST for any graph.

The second one is not always true. It is always true if the entire graph is a 
cycle and thus every node has 2 edges incident to it. However, in the general case, 
an edge `(u,v)` of weight `k` is never on MST whenever there is a path between the nodes `u` and `v` 
connecting them at a total weight less than `k`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your claims are valid. The problem is that you are only considering a cycle in a larger graph.

Consider for example a graph G consisting of 6 nodes in a cycle (with random weights >1). Your claims might hold for that graph but now add 1 node in the center of the graph and connect it with 6 links of cost 1. The MST of your entire graph now will consist of only those 6 edges (which form a star).

If you now look at your claims, you'll see:

- The lightest edge in your cycle does not belong to the MST (=star)
- None of the edges in the cycle are in the MST